# Send an object from php(view) to controller(php) via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Good day.
I have a page where in announcements are displayed.
In every minute I would like to check if there are any changes on the announcement.
if there are any changes I should update the content of the page.
Therefore I need to send back the old announcements to the controller for checking.
But my problem is I don't how to send an entire object from database back to the controller. 
(I can send only plain single data type like string, int etc)

below is the overview of my code
Thank you in advance.

**my view(php)**

```
<div class="row " id="tabapp_news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='tickercontainer'>
            <div class='mask'>
              <ul id="telop">
                <?php 
                foreach ($announces as $announce) {
                    echo '<li>' . $announce->comment . '</li>';
                }
                ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $announces = [];
    $desk_id = Yii::$app->request->get(DESK_KEYWORD);
    if (!empty($desk_id)) {
        $desk = Desk::find()
                    ->where((['id' => $desk_id]))
                    ->one();
        if ($desk) {
            $announces = Announce::getOpeningAnnouncesByDesk($desk->id);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('announce', [
            'announces' => $announces,
            'desk' => $desk,
            ]);
}


public function actionCheckNewAnnounce()
{
    $announces = Yii::$app->request->post('announces');;
    $desk_id = Yii::$app->request->get(DESK_KEYWORD);
    if (!empty($desk_id)) {
        $desk = Desk::find()
                    ->where((['id' => $desk_id]))
                    ->one();
        if ($desk) {
            $new_announces = Announce::getOpeningAnnouncesByDesk($desk->id);

            if (array_diff($new_announces, $announces)) {
                return $this->render('announces', [
                    'announces' => $new_announces,
                    'desk' => $desk,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

**my javascript/ajax**

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/check-new-single',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {announces: $("#info").data('announces')},
            method: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response != "") {
                    $('#telop').empty();
                    $('#telop').append(response);
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ajax communication failure.");
            }
        });
    }, 60000);
```

Comment: After one minute , do u want to display only new announces or append new with old ones ?

Comment: Hi, I just need to display the new one.

Comment: Does this `$new_announces = Announce::getOpeningAnnouncesByDesk($desk->id);` give new announces ?

Comment: Please check the answer , it is posted hoping your ajax and controller logic are correct , but if not please comment the response you are getting vs expected

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort. I just need to send the old announces(an aray of announce ActiveRecord objects from database) back to the controller from the view( view(php)->ajax->controller(php) ) but    doing this leads to error   echo '<input type="hidden" name="info" id="info_announce" data-announces="' . $announces . '">';

Comment: I dont think thats the efficient way for you to achieve this , U should send only the ids of existing announces from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Your View (index.php)**

```
<div class="row " id="tabapp_news">
<div class="container">
    <div class='tickercontainer'>
        <div class='mask'>
          <ul id="telop">
            <?php 
             echo $this->render('annnounce',['announces' => $announces])
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**View (announce.php)**

```
<?php
    foreach ($announces as $announce) {
                echo '<li>' . $announce->comment . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

**JS**

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check-new-announce',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {announces: $("#info").data('announces')},
        method: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != "") {
                $('#telop').html(response);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ajax communication failure.");
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```

**Controller Action**

*Change render to render Ajax*

```
public function actionCheckNewAnnounce()
{
    $announces = Yii::$app->request->post('announces');;
    $desk_id = Yii::$app->request->get(DESK_KEYWORD);
    if (!empty($desk_id)) {
        $desk = Desk::find()
                ->where((['id' => $desk_id]))
                ->one();
        if ($desk) {
           $new_announces = Announce::getOpeningAnnouncesByDesk($desk->id);

            if (array_diff($new_announces, $announces)) {
                return $this->renderAjax('announce', [
                   'announces' => $new_announces,
               ]);
           }
       }
   }
   return "";
}
```